# How do I make my server trigger push notification on new record inserted?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I managed to implement push notification in my app.

Now As the title says **how do you make the server trigger a push notification on new record inserted ?**

All tutorials I see explain how to set up the push notification, but I need to find a good way to accomplish that.

I thought about creating a script to run on a cron job, and check database and fields.

What is the best way to achieve that? any suggestion?

Comment: Whose code is inserting records? Yours?

Comment: I mean its my database and I have users from another app inserting the data

Comment: So I presume it's not your code. In that case, can you talk to the developer of the other application, ask them to provide a hook?

Comment: Everything is mine, the apps, the server, the database

Comment: Okay then, what's the problem? Take the code that inserts the record (the ones that should trigger the push), modify it so that it sends a push message.

Comment: push script is written in php, the others apps are in java, objective-c and ASP.NET, thats why  I thought about triggering it from the DB

Comment: The DB isn't in PHP either. :) You can push GCM messages from Java and ASP.net, too; look it up. Never heard of server side Objective C.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49756/discussion-between-al-pacino-and-seva-alekseyev)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a billion options you know:

1. push the notification as you inserting the data.
2. Write a script to run a cron job.

Option #1 is better in my opinion. but when you have to many apps doing the `INSERT` and you have not designed your apps to implement the push notification from the beginning than you left with option #2

Answer (score 0):

you need to track push notification id of device you need to push notification to.
if User A need to receive a push notification . you need to store devices token on you database under User A record. and when user A records inserted you need to do push on device token according to user token. sorry just typed in rush i ll edit it soon

Answer (score 0):

You could use the on recive function. so the triger will be after reciving the sms and inserting.